# ClassNotFoundException when developing Eclipse plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on an Eclipse plug in (basically it gets posts from social networks such as Facebook and Twitter). I have various plug-in projects and I have one of them which makes use of another. I include the latter project in my build path and it compiles OK. However when I run the projects (Run As – > Eclipse Application) I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Previously I had a similar issue but I was referencing a JAR file so apart from including it in the build path, I included it in the classpath from the Runtime tab in Eclipse and it worked fine. However Eclipse only seems to allow JAR files and not plug-in projects in the workspace to be included in the classpath.

I've tried various ways to try to include the plug-in project I need but the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException still comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the plugin you are using as a dependency of the plugin you are writing.  Once that is setup open the Run Configuration for your project, click on the Plug-Ins tab and select the "Add Required Plugins" button.

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329293/eclipse-classpath-and-noclassdeffounderror/2329472#2329472).

Comment: 10x a lot! That was it! 

Thanks again
Krt_Malta